# Trouble Creating and saving to file in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file, save

I am trying to run some sample code and am having trouble creating and saving to a file.

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction) example
{
    NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSURL *docsurl = [fm URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask  appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
    myfolder = [docsurl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];
    NSError * err = nil;
    BOOL ok = [fm createDirectoryAtURL:myfolder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&err];
    ok = [label.text writeToURL:myfolder atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];       
}

-(IBAction) load
{
    label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myfolder
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

I want it to save the first label's text to the file when I push the first button.  When I push the second button, I want it to read what is in the file and make the second label text that.  However when I push the second button, the second label just goes blank.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't appear to be checking the result of any of the methods you call. Do any of them succeed? What is the value of `ok`? Does `docsurl` end with a slash? Do you need to append one before appending `MyFolder`, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest actually using those NSError objects. I also suggest using the default NSFileManager.

```
-(IBAction) example
{
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *docsurl = [fm URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask  appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error];
    myfolder = [docsurl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];
    NSError * err = nil;

    if ([fm createDirectoryAtURL:myfolder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&err]) {
        if ([label.text writeToURL:myfolder atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err]) {

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"%@", err);
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", err);
    }


}

-(IBAction) load
{
    NSError *err;
    if ([[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myfolder
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err]) {
        label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myfolder
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", err);
    }
}
```

This code will not work as is, but it will print out whatever errors you are encountering which should help you solve the problem.

Comment: I tried running your code and the output I get when I push the example button is: 2012-05-31 17:53:05.927 example[3068:10703] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x7549230 {NSFilePath=/Users/rawsonhunter/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/2E92DC0F-94F0-41ED-AE47-0A2EB7FAE2DF/Documents/MyFolder, NSUnderlyingError=0x7548ce0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory"}

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. It is saying that you are trying to write to a directory. Take a look at the code. You first make the folder with the myfolder URL. Then you try to write a file to the same URL. You have to make a new URL that represents the file.